# I'm struggling with the new syntax and with GeoGraphics

Tags: syntax, geographics

I've used Mathematica since the mid-90's, but I'm a beginner with some of the new syntax.

The thing I'm trying to do is not only have a polar map of the Northern Hemisphere,

[image]

```
Graphics @@ 
 GeoGraphics[GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", GeoCenter -> {90, 0}, 
  GeoRange -> "World", GeoGridLines -> Automatic, Background -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 300]
```

But also, I'd like to mark individual cities on this map, kind of like we have here.
[image]

But I'm getting stumped with a simple syntax issue.  How do I include a GeoMarker within the structure I already have in order to indicate where various cities are on this map?

So far, I've tried couple of things.
[image]

This is close, but the range is cropped.

[image]
This, clearly, is the wrong shape.

I'm also not sure how to paste this code in this forum without it looking long, ugly and terrible.

Comment: Move the `GeoProjection` option out of the list to be next to the other options (`GeoCenter`, etc...)

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 6):

We can query `GeoProjectionData` for the complete options for the default form of the specified projection:

```
GeoProjectionData["Orthographic"]

{"Orthographic", {"Centering" -> {0, 0},"GridOrigin" -> {0, 0},"ReferenceModel" -> 1}}
```

This suggests we can pass a "Centering" sub-option to achieve what I think you're asking for:

```
With[{fresno = 
   Entity["City", {"Fresno", "California", "UnitedStates"}]},
 GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[fresno], GeoRange -> "World", 
  GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", {"Centering" -> 
      fresno["Coordinates"], "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, 
     "ReferenceModel" -> 1}}]]
```

[image]